# Passing data when using SearchView in the action bar

Tags: android, android-intent

How do I pass data to the Activity handling a search when I use the new SearchView functionality?

Before SearchView, I would do this with the search dialog by doing this:

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
     Bundle appData = new Bundle();
     appData.putBoolean("somename", true);
     startSearch(null, false, appData, false);
     return true;
}
```

But that method doesn't seem to get called when the SearchView on the action bar is used. So how do I pass data?

Thanks.